# Moving items inside a ListView, how to add animation?

Tags: c#, listview, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I have a `ListView` in my *Windows Phone 8.1 Runtime* app, which has such bindings:

In XAML:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding myBinding}" ... >
```

In code behind:

```
this.defaultViewModel["myBinding"] = s; //s is an ObservableCollection.
```

I'm moving some of the items using `Move` function of `ObservableCollection`:

```
ObservableCollection<MyItem> pi = (ObservableCollection<MyItem>)this.defaultViewModel["myBinding"];
pi.Move(5,6);
```

The moving operation is working, but I want to add animation to it (I want the items to actually start moving to each other's place)

I tried adding `ReorderThemeTransition` to the `ListView`, but it's not working.

```
<ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <VirtualizingStackPanel>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel.ChildrenTransitions>
                <TransitionCollection>           
                    <ReorderThemeTransition/>
                </TransitionCollection>
            </VirtualizingStackPanel.ChildrenTransitions>
        </VirtualizingStackPanel>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListView.ItemsPanel>
```

How can I implement such animation to my `ListView`?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the code snippet you're looking for is

```
<ListView.ItemContainerTransitions>
    <TransitionCollection>
        <AddDeleteThemeTransition/>
    </TransitionCollection>
</ListView.ItemContainerTransitions>
```

[source](http://www.visuallylocated.com/post/2014/06/24/Page-transitions-and-animations-in-Windows-Phone-Runtime.aspx)

Animations are actually really subtle though.

Comment: I tried this, but it's not working. The ListView immediately shows the new order. This method works if I remove and insert item (which is a terrible animation, actually :) ) but nothing happens when I use `Move`.

Comment: Have you tried with ReorderThemeTransition or RepositionThemeTransition? I'm being told that ListView has all of these by default. If so, that's as far as you can go with native transitions I guess.

Comment: ReorderThemeTransition does nothing, and RepositionThemeTransition hides everything and moves every item from bottom to its place. However, the effect that I want is available in native messaging app (when you receive a new message, the thread moves to top) but I have no idea why ReorderThemeTransition doesn't work.